# Record exists in Python Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with multiple columns. I need to check if a record exists but only comparing by certain columns.
Is there a better way to do it than:

```
 #df has the following columns  df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['DIR', FILE_NAME', 'A-HASH', 'P-HASH', 'D-HASH', 'W-HASH','SIZE', 'TAGSIZE', 'FILE_CREATE_DATE'])
 df = pd.read_csv(mainDFfile, index_col = ['INDEX'])
 for base in filter(functools.partial(re.match, "(?i).*jpe?g$"),
                       filenames):
        fn = os.path.join(dirpath, base)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(fn)
        if ((df['DIR'] == dirpath) & (df['FILE_NAME'] == base) & (df['SIZE'] == file_size)).any():
            print('FILE EXISTS', fn)
        else:
           #add file to DB
```

Comment: What is the issue?  Does the above code not work as intended or bad performance?

Comment: Just thought there maybe a cleaner, more flexible way.
What if I need a function like:

    compare_by([column set], [variable list])

Comment: We need to see more context than one line. Where is this `if` statement placed?

Comment: Added more context.